# OpenLayers with VueJS - empty div in place of map

Tags: vue.js, openlayers

I'm trying to implement a simple world map in a Vue application. I have created a MapContainer component that is then imported into my main app. Below is the code for MapContainer.vue:

```
<template>
  <div
    ref="map-root"
    style="width: 100%, height: 100%">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import View from 'ol/View';
  import Map from 'ol/Map';
  import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
  import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
  import 'ol/ol.css';

  export default {
    name: 'MapContainer',
    components: {},
    props: {},
    mounted() {
      new Map({
        target: this.$refs['map-root'],

        layers: [
          new TileLayer({
            source: new OSM()
          })
        ],
    
        view: new View({
          zoom: 0,
          center: [0, 0],
          constrainResolution: true
        })
      });
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

I am registering the MapContainer component and then simply placing it inside a div in the parent component. When I import this component and try to use it, I get an empty div in place of the map. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the parent component's code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <map-container></map-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import MapContainer from '../mapping/MapContainter.vue';
  
  export default {
    components: {
      'map-container': MapContainer
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: please show your app.vue code also.

Comment: I've added the parent component's code

Comment: Your parent component seems correct & also your mapContainer. Can you change your `ref="map-root"` to `ref="mapRoot"` & change your target from `target: this.$refs['map-root']` to `target: this.$refs.mapRoot`. Let me know if that works?.

Comment: That proposed change doesn't make any sense, @dhruwlalan. dashes in refs are totally legal and handled properly. It's pretty much like telling OP to change the color of their chair.

Comment: @user141, from what you're describing you're having CSS issues. Inspect the markup and verify the map element is there. Make sure it has a `height`. Also check the docs of the map plugin you're using and verify you're not missing any CSS import. Basically go over their getting started and basic examples and see if you spot anything missing in yours.

Comment: Also check network requests for any failed resources, warnings or errors which might point in the right direction, If you can't spot anything wrong, please create a runnable [mcve] with what you have (use codesandbox.io) and I'll have a look.

Comment: @tao Hmm, since he got an empty div instead of the map & that type of refs syntax I haven't used before I thought to reverify it if that works. Rest I agree with your comment.:)

Comment: @dhruwlalan, empty div might mean a div containing a map with an actual height of `0`. Besides, I have used dashes in `$refs` and they work, even though they're a bit more cumbersome to write. And it has nothing to do with Vue, really. It's plain JS: have an object/class member containing a dash? reference it as string with array notation: `this['my-function']()`.

Comment: @tao Thanks for the explanation. Got it! Now i'll also use dashes in my $refs.:))

Comment: @tao you were right, it was to do with CSS being weird, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by adding the following class to the div with the ref:

```
.map {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 600px !important;
}
```

(The !important's might not be strictly necessary).

Comment: Fully agree the `!important` is not strictly necessary. If you want it *clean*, you can inspect the rules being applied and write a selector with same specificity and apply it last.